# Why is onBackPressed() not being called?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am attempting to override onBackPressed(). However it appears to not detect when I click the back button in the action bar.

I currently have this code:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()  {

    Log.i("DATA", "Hit onBackPressed()");
    super.onBackPressed();

}
```

The log message never appears in the LogCat. I know that this log statement works because it is copied from another method with a different message that DOES display in the LogCat.

I have searched for answers, and I have tried using onKeyDown and detecting if it is the BACK button being clicked but I still have the same issue.
Information about the project:

- Android Studio 0.9.3
- Method is located in blank activity
- target sdk 21
- minimum sdk 15
- testing device is a Samsung Galaxy 5 (not emulator)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

EDIT:

This is a copy of my working code (this is test code so the activity name is not descriptive):

```
public class MainActivity2 extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activity2);
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);//Displays the back button
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main_activity2, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:

            Log.i("DATA", "Hit Actionbar Back Button");

            return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

}
```

The message "Hit Actionbar Back Button" now appears in the LogCat.

Comment: `the back button in the action bar.` because the button in the actionbar is not a back button. It is the `up` button. see http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`onBackPressed()` is invoked when user clicks on a hardware back button (or on the 'up' button in the navigation bar), not the button in the action bar. For this one you need to override `onOptionsItemSelected()` method. Example:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            // click on 'up' button in the action bar, handle it here
            return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't have to be a hardware button, it also works on the soft back button in the navigation bar.

Comment: @Lars oops, good remark! all android phones I had so far had hardware navigaion buttons, thus I'm always forgetting about buttons in the navigation bar.

Comment: Thanks man, this saved me from troubleshooting the wrong problem.

Comment: After spending so much time on this, i found this answer and thanks it got worked.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code,

```
public class MainActivity2 extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}


@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onBackPressed();

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "back press is call", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
}
```

Comment: The Toast still did not appear. @aga had the correct answer. Thanks!

Comment: @kkimble006 can you please share you activity full code.

Comment: @kkimble006 I test this code in phone and emulator, it's work fine, please check it.

Comment: I tested this code and it does work with the Hardware back button. My interest was in overriding the Action Bar back button. This code does not work for that (I tested it). Thanks anyway @KrunalI!