# Popbackstack Finishes Activity in OnBackPressed

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an Activity with two Fragments (List & Details), in onCreate(), I start the List Fragment if savedInstance  is null like so

```
 public static final int CLIENT_LIST_FRAGMENT = 1;
 public static final int CLIENT_DETAILS_FRAGMENT = 2;
 private int currentFragment = 0;

if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            //On first run, start the list fragment
            if (currentFragment == 0) {
                ClientListFragment listFrag = new ClientListFragment();
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .add(R.id.container_client, listFrag, Constants.CLIENT_LIST_FRAGMENT_TAG)
                        .commit();
                currentFragment = CLIENT_LIST_FRAGMENT;
            } else {
                switch (currentFragment) {
                    case CLIENT_LIST_FRAGMENT:
                        addListFragment();
                        break;
                    case CLIENT_DETAILS_FRAGMENT:
                        addDetailsFragment(0);
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
```

And here is the method that add the DetailsFragment and ListFragment as needed

```
 private void addListFragment(){
        ClientDetailsFragment listFrag = new ClientDetailsFragment();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container_client, listFrag, Constants.CLIENT_LIST_FRAGMENT_TAG)
                .addToBackStack("details")
                .commit();
        currentFragment = CLIENT_LIST_FRAGMENT;
    }

    private void addDetailsFragment(long companyId){
        ClientDetailsFragment detailsFrag = ClientDetailsFragment.newInstance(companyId);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container_client, detailsFrag, Constants.CLIENT_DETAILS_TAG)
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .commit();
        currentFragment = CLIENT_DETAILS_FRAGMENT;

    }
```

This works as expected except that when I click the back button from the Details Fragment, instead of taking me back to the List Fragment, it actually finishes the Activity. It goes back to the List Fragment for a split second and then finishes the host Activity and goes back to the calling Activity. How can I stop this behavior, after going through a lot of onBackpress related question on SO here is my overide of the onBackPressed

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (currentFragment == CLIENT_DETAILS_FRAGMENT){
            getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();
        }else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Activity onBackPressed() should be:

For android.support.v4.app.Fragment

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 1)
        getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    else
        finish();
}
```

For android.app.Fragment

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 1)
        getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    else
        finish();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I usually check whether the current fragment instance belongs to the fragment that invoked *onBackPressed()*. This code is untested; it's just to give you an idea on how to proceed. I hope you are not calling *this.finish()* on this `Activity`.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Fragment fragment = getSuportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(Constants.CLIENT_DETAILS_TAG);
    if (fragment instanceof ClientDetailsFragment) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();
    }
    else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Thanks and I will try your code in a bit, I have troubleshoot to the fact that onDestroy gets called no matter how I handled onbackpressed so my challenge now is to figure out how to stop onDestroy from being called when I onBackpressed is called

Comment: Well, that means `this.finish()` is being called by the _application_ or the _system_ **(this instance of the activity is being destroyed to save space)** [Check documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html).

Comment: Hmm, on a simple App. Thanks, I am trying to see how to prevent that. Thanks for your code, it is pointing me to the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Good Lord, I was chasing the wrong shadow for two days. I was listening, handling and overriding the wrong event.

This SO question saved me [Why is onBackPressed() not being called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27045551/why-is-onbackpressed-not-being-called)

And the gist is *"onBackPressed() is invoked when user clicks on a hardware back button (or on the 'up' button in the navigation bar), not the button in the action bar. For this one you need to override onOptionsItemSelected() method. Example:"*

I was catching this event the fragment and calling getActivity.onBackpressed. When I stopped this, it became obvious to me that the onBackPressed is not being called. Here is my solution, may not be optimal but it works

```
if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home){
            if (currentFragment == CLIENT_DETAILS_FRAGMENT){
                getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();
                currentFragment  = CLIENT_LIST_FRAGMENT;
                return true;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (currentFragment == 0) {
            ClientListFragment listFrag = new ClientListFragment();
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container_client, listFrag, Constants.CLIENT_LIST_FRAGMENT_TAG)
                    .commit();
            currentFragment = CLIENT_LIST_FRAGMENT;
        }
```

while changing this add to addToBackStack()

and,
change onBackPressed() like,

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
 if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() == 1) {
     MainActivity.this.finish();
 }
 else {
    getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
  }
}
```

Hope, this will work.